# fail to locate template html of imported commponent in Angular2

Tags: angular

I was working on an Angular2 demo with multiple components. The demo bootstraps with an AppComponent, where I imported other components in the template html of AppComponent. I was successful to setup the demo and see the content of AppComponent, but failed to load other components.

Here is the code example of my angular2 components

app.component.html

```
<div id="map">
    <navigator></navigator>
</div>
```

app.component.ts

```
import {Component, View} from 'angular2/core';
import {NavigatorComponent} from '../components/navigator/navigator.component'

@Component({
    selector: 'app'
})
@View({
    templateUrl: './app/app.component.html', 
    directives: [NavigatorComponent]
})
export class AppComponent { }
```

navigator.component.html

```
<input type="text">
```

navigator.component.ts

```
import {Component, View} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'navigator'
})
@View({
    templateUrl: './components/navigator/navigator.component.html'
})
export class NavigatorComponent { }
```

When I set up the server and tried to see the app, I had the following error

```
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost:3000/components/navigator/navigator.component"
```

and

```
Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:3000/components/navigator/navigator.component
Error loading http://localhost:3000/components/navigator/navigator.component as "../components/navigator/navigator.component" from http://localhost:3000/app/app.component.js
```

Obviously, the server tried find a navigator.component, but it didn't exist. However, when I tried http://localhost:3000/components/navigator/navigator.component.html, I succeed to see the page with a textbox.

So the problem seemed to be the missing html extension, but I had no idea how it happened.

I will appreciate any suggestion and answer to solve the problem. Thanks in advance.

---

If you want to fully experience the bug, please go to the project's repo (https://github.com/haoliangyu/angular2-leaflet-starter) and do the following steps:

1. uncomment line 12 at **public_src/app/app.component.ts**
2. set up the app
3. go to **localhost:3000** and check the error

---

**Update**:

This problem was solved by resisting the other component in the SystemJS config, like

```
System.config({
    defaultJSExtension: true,
    packages: {
        'app': {
            format: 'register'
        },
        'components/navigator': {
            format: 'register'
        }
    }
});
```

This helped the app to locate other components :)

Comment: how are you hosting your server? with browser-sync?

Comment: I used the package [lite-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lite-server). According to its dependency file, I guess yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not that it can't find the template file. But it is unable to load the `navigator.component.js`.

It is trying to load it from http://localhost:3000/components/navigator/navigator.component, but it should be loading from the map 'app', ergo: http://localhost:3000/app/components/navigator/navigator.component.js. The `js` extension will get added by the default extension set in the SystemJS configuration.

The reason the error goes away after you comment the line 12 in `app.component.ts` is that even though the import statement of the `navigator.component.ts` still remains in the code, the typescript compiler won't add it to the actual output, because the class is not used in the current file.

I could not install your project, because it seems like you've already done some changes on it. But i believe the fix for this is to change the import location of the `navigator.component` inside the `app.component.ts`:

```
import {NavigatorComponent} from './../components/navigator/navigator.component'
```

Notice how I've prepended the current folder `./`

---

Better should  be to either add a base href tag in your index.html:

```
<base href="http://localhost/app/">
```

Or to serve your website from the `app` folder in such a way that `http://localhost` actually refers to the app folder, and not its parent

Comment: Although it wasn't the solution, but you guided me to the right direction. Thanks

Comment: What was the solution if I may ask?

Comment: I need to register other components, beside the AppComponet, at the System.config. Please see the update at the bottom of my question, and this script is at public_src/index.html of the project.

Comment: though folder placing is right, i come across, if I dont add module.id, html not found error occurs.@Component({
 moduleId: module.id, // DONT MISS MODULE ID, ELSE IT SHOWS .HTML NOT FOUND ERROR 
 selector: 'communication',
 templateUrl: 'communication.component.html'
})

Comment: @HydTechie Thank you for your feedback, I was following the Heroes tut, and for some reason I could not find the solution. Your solution is correct.